# Echo Output send next page in php

Tags: redirect

I want to redirect the echo output result in next page..where  am using echo "Result from SP procOutput_sum:::::$SP_VAL"; ...:::"SP_VAL" i want to refer this output next page..

```
 <?php

   $ipAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
       $macAddr=false;
       $out_put="";
     //echo "Your IP address is : $ipAddress";
        #run the external command, break output into lines
      $arp=`arp -a $ipAddress`;
      $lines=explode("\n", $arp);

      #look for the output line describing our IP address
         foreach($lines as $line)
          {
           $cols=preg_split('/\s+/', trim($line));
         if ($cols[0]==$ipAddress)
        {
        $macAddr=$cols[1];
           }
       }

     ?>

        <?php

if(isset($_POST['webpanel'])){
      $mobileno=$_POST['mobileno'];
      $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $email=$_POST['femail'];
     $fmessage=$_POST['fmessage'];
     $colorRadio=$_POST['colorRadio'];
    $demo1=$_POST['demo1'];
    $flag="CALL_ORIGIN";
  $client="GALACTIC";


     $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "call_conference");

$call = $mysqli->prepare('CALL CALL_ORIGIN(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,@out_put)');
$call->bind_param('ssssssssss',$mobileno,$flag,$fname,$email
,$fmessage,$ipAddress,$macAddr,     $colorRadio,$demo1,$client);
    $call->execute();
     $select = $mysqli->query('SELECT @out_put');
      $result = $select->fetch_assoc();
     $SP_VAL = $result['@out_put'];
     echo "Result from SP procOutput_sum:::::$SP_VAL";

       if(empty($mobileno) || empty($fname)){
       echo "SP OUT_VAL:$output";
echo "<label class='err'>All field is required</label>";
}

  elseif(!is_numeric($mobileno)){
echo "<label class='err'>Mobile no must be numeric</label>";
}
    else{

        echo " &nbsp; Your IP address is : $ipAddress and Your Mac   address              is:$macAddr and CALL_SCHEDULER_TIME::: $demo1";
    }
  }
     ?>

    <body style="background:white;">
   <center>
      <h3>Hi <?php echo $fname; ?></h3><br/>
   <h2>Your call is transferred to our Server</h2>
      <img src="img/phone.gif">
     </center>
    <br/>
     <?php echo "Result from SP procOutput_sum:::::$SP_VAL";?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of trying to redirect the echo, you should rather pass the content of this echo in the `SESSION` variable, then redirect to the other file in which you will acess again the `SESSION` variable in order to echo the previous content.

Here's an example:
[PHP Pass Data with Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321071/php-pass-data-with-redirect)