# Redirecting not working in PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I want to redirect to another page after inserting values in the database, but it is not redirecting. It remains on the same page. No error/warning is shown.

My code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btn-submit'])) {
    $asth = $user->runQuery("SELECT MAX(Sr) as Sr FROM answer");
    $asth->execute();
    $aresult = $asth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $atf = ($aresult['Sr']);
    $aI = "1";
    $acid = $atf + $aI;
    $arn = $fddate.$ydate.$mdate.$frandno.$acid;
    $count = $i;
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $count; $j++) { 
        $ufname = trim($_POST['radio'.$j]);
        $Qrn = trim($_POST['qid'.$j]); 
        $istmt = $user->runQuery("INSERT INTO answer(ARN,Ans,QRN,SRN) VALUES(:user_arn, :user_crn, :user_qrn, :user_srn)");
        $istmt->bindparam(":user_qrn",$Qrn);
        $istmt->bindparam(":user_crn",$ufname);
        $istmt->bindparam(":user_arn",$arn);
        $istmt->bindparam(":user_srn",$srn);
        $istmt->execute();  
    }

    return $istmt;

    $locationei = "result.php";
    $locatione = $web.$locationei;
    $user->redirect($locatione);
}
?>
```

In the starting of page:

```
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user = new USER();
```

In `class.user.php`:

```
public function redirect($url) {
    header("Location: $url");
}
```

Comment: what is that `}` doing in 2 line?

Comment: Im assuming we are supposed to guess what your "$user->redirect($locatione)" does, right?

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal it is end for condition which was started earlier

Comment: What is there in $web you've got to elaborate a little more

Comment: @vicbyte is the question fine after editing?

Comment: @BlackMamba `$web` is defined as `http://localhost/quiz/` in another file which is included in main file

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal this https://www.dropbox.com/s/kdqgyy0znh3cxla/quiz.php?dl=0 will help you for understanding the question better.

Comment: @AkshayMandale the code that you've written is very scattered and not concise. According to me you are not going in a right way. You are mixing php and html both at the same time, which is somehow not good approach. You should keep separate file as php and html

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might lie in here:

```
return $istmt;

$locationei = "result.php";
$locatione = $web.$locationei;
$user->redirect($locatione);
```

Once you return a value, function stops execution and skips the rest of the code...

Also, you should ALWAYS exit() after redirection, as the redirection doesnt stop script execution and has been a source of problems in the past.

```
public function redirect($url)
{
   header("Location: $url");
   exit();
}
```

Comment: So should I remove `return` and try? Or something else should i expect?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that return anyways?

Comment: Nothing to do with return

Comment: Then just remove it. You dont need to return anything, especially since you are redirecting.

Comment: After coding as described I got warning and it doesn't redirects

Comment: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp64\www\quiz\quiz.php:184) in C:\wamp64\www\quiz\class.user.php on line 399` is the warning

Comment: You are already outputting some text or other informations on the page. You cant do that if you redirect. It does point you to the right lines tho :)

Comment: Yes, some things are displayed using `PHP`, but I need redirect after submitting

Comment: Lemme repeat myself, you CANT output if you plan to redirect. Whats the point of outputting anyways if the user cant see it (he's getting redirected from that page).

Comment: Should I  provide you a code which will help you for better understanding?

Comment: Theres nothing to understand really. If you try to ouput text before you redirect, theres no point. Redirect takes you to another page, which means anything you would ouput to that point would be erased anyways.

Comment: I am sure you will able to understand why I have some text and want redirect at submit

Comment: I'm looking at it and you still fail to understand that redirect erases the text you previously outputted. Meaning none of the text you put BEFORE redirect will be visible on the new page.
If you want to pass some output onto the page you are redirecting you need to pass it via variables and output on the new page.

Comment: So what should I code that goes to another page after submitting, It's a quiz script which displays question from database...

Comment: So how to do for my script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321071/php-pass-data-with-redirect
This should answer your questions.

Comment: So, Where should I paste: `$_SESSION['message'] = "Post successfully posted.";` after query is done or some where else?

Comment: You can store whatever output you might want to show on the new page in it. Thats not the top-of-the-line idea, but since youre learning this will be much simpler than alternate solutions.

Comment: But where to code it? At the end of PHP or any other line?

Comment: `{ 
//if(isset($_POST['btn-submit'])) {
$tufname = trim($_POST['tradio'.$tj]);
$tQrn = trim($_POST['tqid'.$tj]); 
$tistmt = $user->runQuery("INSERT INTO answer(ARN,Ans,QRN,SRN) VALUES(:user_arn, :user_tcrn, :user_tqrn, :user_srn)");
$tistmt->bindparam(":user_tqrn",$tQrn);
$tistmt->bindparam(":user_tcrn",$tufname);
$tistmt->bindparam(":user_arn",$arn);
$tistmt->bindparam(":user_srn",$srn);
$tistmt->execute(); 

}
$_SESSION['message'] = "Post successfully posted.";

}
}
}
}
?>`

Comment: Its not.
You should definetly stop whatever you are trying to do and learn to separate html from php. This will help you greatly in what you are trying to achieve and help you understand couple of things along the way.