# How to store current URL in a PHP variable and break the reference to $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?

Tags: php, global-variables

Say I'm on **/page_1.php**. I run the following code under a certain condition:

```
global $URL_BEFORE_PAGE2;
$URL_BEFORE_PAGE2 = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header('location: /page_2.php');
```

I am now on **/page_2.php**. This page contains the following link:

```
<a href="<?=$URL_BEFORE_PAGE2?>">Return to Previous Page</a>
```

**PROBLEM:** The link using *$URL_BEFORE_PAGE2* points to **/page_2.php** instead of the expected **/page_1.php**.

I assume the problem is that *$URL_BEFORE_PAGE2* is storing a reference to *$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']* instead of just storing the value. How can I keep the original value of *$URL_BEFORE_PAGE2* without it updating every time *$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']* changes?

Comment: you have to store that in the session.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Pass Data with Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321071/php-pass-data-with-redirect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page_1.php, use the following code to create a session that will store the uri

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['URL_BEFORE_PAGE2'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header('location: /index2.php');
```

On page_2.php, simply use the session to get the uri again

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<a href="<?=$_SESSION['URL_BEFORE_PAGE2']?>">Return to Previous Page</a>
```

[More info on sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

[session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: Please explain why my answer deserved a downvote so I can improve it.

Comment: I certainly did not downvote. I got caught up in other things but just tried this now and it worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with javascript:

```js
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
```

You could do that with PHP like this:

```html
<?php
  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```